# получить случайные неповторяющиеся значения для 3 случайных переменных из 4-х

Tags: java

Есть метод, в нем инициализированы четыре переменных `int t1=0, t2=0, t3=0,t4=0;`. Как можно реализовать, что бы в методе одна из четырех (рандомно) переменных осталась со значением `0`, а три оставшихся переменных получили рандомное значение в диапозоне от 1 до 100 и что бы они еще и не повторялись между собой.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Примерно так. Думаю разберетесь.

```
// заполняем список числами 1.. 100
List<Integer> fill = new ArrayList<>();
for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
    fill.add(i + 1);
}
// перемешиваем и забираем первые 4
Collections.shuffle(fill);  
List<Integer> t = new ArrayList<>(fill.subList(0, 4));
// выбираем элемент в списке по рандомному индексу и заменяем на 0
Random rand = new Random();
int idx = rand.nextInt(4);
t.set(idx, 0);
System.out.println(t);

int t1 = t.get(0);
int t2 = t.get(1);
// .. etc
```

Comment: Что-то сложно...

Comment: И неэффективно.

Comment: @Qwertiy а пример простого и эффективного покажете? можно не на яве

Comment: @Qwertiy, мне кажется примеры надо приводить так, чтобы было понятно автору, а оптимизировать что-либо не зная контекста не имеет смысла. Запостите свое решение, как это принято на оригинальном форуме.

Comment: Неэффективность тут не в оптимизациях, а в алгоритме. Если вместо 100 попросить так же 4 числа до 1000000, то будет проделано несколько миллионов операций, которых в общем-то быть не должно.

Comment: Ушел гуглить курсы телепатов.

Comment: @zRrr, не думаю, что линейно возможно. Но квадрат или куб от количества выбираемых чисел точно возможен.

Comment: @Qwertiy не та ссылка, извиняюсь. По [ссылке](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3724708/5661663) утверждает, что линейно от размера выборки, если поиск среди выбранных будет работать за О(1), т.е. получается, что квадрат в худшем случае.

Comment: @zRrr, похоже, но я не уверен, что распределение там равномерное не портится.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно зачем это надо...

Но оставляем t1 без изменений.

Для t2 генерируем случайноей число от 1 до 100.

Для t3 присваиваем t2, а потом в циклt `while(t2 == t3)` для t3 генерируем случайное число от 1 до 100.

После этого аналогично поступаем с t4. Присваиваем ему значение t3 и выполняем цикл `while(t3 == t4 || t2 == t4)`

Для более красивого решения и избавления от индуского кода можно отказаться от использования переменных t1 - t4 и использовать массив целых чисел.

Comment: это было бы просто, если бы мне не нужно было чтобы ноль оставался у разных переменных, а не постоянно у t1

Comment: @МаксимФомичёв красиво это решается при использовании массива.  Если и дальше следовать заветам братьев наших индийских - то как вариант, после этого сгенерировать случайное число от 2 до 4 и в switch сделать замену значение для указанной переменной с t1

Comment: я вопрос немного изменил, про индийский код, просьба не писать, каждый проходит этот этап

Comment: @МаксимФомичёв Дело в том что давно существуют и есть на просторах решения для заполнения массивов случайными значениями, а так же для перемешивания значений в массивах. Для этого есть универсальные решения. Для вашего же случая все будет усложняться, если понадобиться ввести еще одну переменную. Если же к переменным жестко привязаны, то проще сделать генерацию с помощью массива, а затем сделать t1=arr[0]; t2=arr[1]; и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void get(){
    java.util.Random random = new java.util.Random();
    int t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4;
    int[] array = new int[4];

    int zeroIndex = random.nextInt(4);
    array[zeroIndex] = 0;

    for(int index = 0; index < 4; index++ ) {
        if(index != zeroIndex){
            int temp = random.nextInt(101);
            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++ ){
                if(array[i] == temp) {
                    i = 0;
                    temp = random.nextInt(101);
                }
            }
            array[index] = temp;
        }
    }

    t_1 = array[0];
    t_2 = array[1];
    t_3 = array[2];
    t_4 = array[3];
}
```

Comment: -   Простое лучше, чем сложное
    -   Если реализацию сложно объяснить — идея плоха.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.