# Массив случайных не повторяющихся чисел

Tags: java, случайные-числа

Нужно заполнить массив из 9 ячеек числами от 1 до 9, чтобы они не повторялись.

1 вариант.

```
int[]ar = new int[9];
ar[0] = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
ar[1] = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
if (ar[1] == ar[0]) {
    ar[1] = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
}
ar[2] = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
if (ar[2] == ar[1] || ar[2] == ar[0]) {
    ar[2] = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
}
ar[3] = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
if (ar[3] == ar[2] || ar[3] == ar[1] || ar[3] == ar[0]) {
    ar[3] = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
}
ar[4] = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
if (ar[4] == ar[3] || ar[4] == ar[2] || ar[4] == ar[1] || ar[4] == ar[0]) {
    ar[4] = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
}
ar[5] = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
if (ar[5] == ar[4] || ar[5] == ar[3] || ar[5] == ar[2] || ar[5] == ar[1] || 
        ar[5] == ar[0]) {
    ar[5] = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
}
ar[6] = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
if (ar[6] == ar[5] || ar[6] == ar[4] || ar[6] == ar[3] || ar[6] == ar[2] ||
        ar[6] == ar[1] || ar[6] == ar[0]) {
    ar[6] = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
}
ar[7] = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
if (ar[7] == ar[6] || ar[7] == ar[5] || ar[7] == ar[4] || ar[7] == ar[3] ||
        ar[7] == ar[2] || ar[7] == ar[1] || ar[7] == ar[0]) {
    ar[7] = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
}
ar[8] = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
if (ar[8] == ar[7] || ar[8] == ar[6] || ar[8] == ar[5] || ar[8] == ar[4] ||
        ar[8] == ar[3] || ar[8] == ar[2] || ar[8] == ar[1] || ar[8] == ar[0]) {
    ar[8] = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
}
```

хорошо что их всего 9.

2 вариант.

```
int[]ar = new int[8];
for (int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    i = (int)(Math.random() * 9 + 1);
    if (ar[i] = ar[i]) {
        ???

    }
}
```

В первом варианте есть проблема: если совпали 2 числа, то он второе меняет, но если и второй раз совпало, то не меняет. Например, выпало `4-6-5-3` и пришло `6`, он его сменит, например, на `4`, а `4` уже не будет менять. Как правильно сделать?

Решать за меня не надо, прошу натолкнуть на мысль.

Comment: Внутренность тела цикла for удаляете. ОБъявляете булеву переменную b. Следом цикл while с условием завязаным на b, в теле которого  устанавливаете b в 0 (допустим)  и генерите случайное число. Также в while делаете еще один цикл for, который проходится по всем числам массива и сравнивает со сгенерированным числом. Если нашлось хоть одно совпадение - значение b должно измениться на 1. Тоесть пока вы не сгенерите число не похожее на все остальные вы не должны выходить из цикла while.

Comment: храните сгенерированные значения в отдельном контейнере и сравнивайте

Comment: @Sublihim Зачем дублировать нагенерённые значения?

Comment: @AK, а кто говорит о дублировании?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Использовать коллекцию `HashSet`, элементы коллекции содержат только уникальные значения и повторы исключены. Будут генерироваться новые числа, пока все ячейки не заполнятся:

```
Set<Integer> generated = new HashSet<Integer>();
Random r = new Random();
while (generated.size() < 9) {
generated.add(r.nextInt(9) + 1);
}
```

[на основе этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/231275/177345)

или `shuffle()` (перемешивание элементов коллекции) расположенных по порядку чисел:

```
List<Integer> fill = new ArrayList<>();
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    fill.add(i + 1);
}
Collections.shuffle(fill);
```

[на основе этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/485976/177345)

Для 9 элементов это не нагрузит чрезмерно систему.

Если нужно именно в массив `int[]`, то преобразование из коллекции не сложное (для второго примера аналогично)

C помощью Apache Commons:

```
int[] arr = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(generated.toArray(new Integer[0]));
```

или в Java 8:

```
 int[] arr = generated.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
```

Другие [варианты преобразования](https://stackoverflow.com/q/718554)

Answer (score 4):

Общая идея довольно проста – генерируем первое число, добавляем его в массив, генерируем второе число, проверяем его наличие в массиве (с помощью цикла, например), если сгенерированное число уже содержится в массиве, генерируем следующее, если не содержится – добавляем его туда.

Предложу такой вариант:

```
final int N = 9;
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(N);
Random random = new Random();

while (arrayList.size() < N) {
    int i = random.nextInt(N) + 1;
    if (!arrayList.contains(i)) {
        arrayList.add(i);
    }
}

int[] randomArray = arrayList.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
```

Этот вариант – самый тривиальный: создаем `ArrayList<Integer>` и наполняем его 9-ю псевдослучайными числами. Если очередное сгенерированное число уже содержится в списке – пропускаем его и генерируем следующее.

В этом варианте, *в среднем*, список заполняется за 25 итераций цикла.

Как альтернативный вариант – можно использовать любую коллекцию, реализующую интерфейс `Set` – они хранят только неповторяющиеся элементы.

Принципиально другой вариант – заполнить список элементами по-порядку, а потом перемешать их:

```
final int N = 9;
ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(N);
for (int i=1; i<=N; i++) {
    arrayList.add(i);
}

Random random = new Random();

for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    int j = random.nextInt(N);
    if (j != i) {
        int tmp = arrayList.get(i);
        arrayList.set(i, arrayList.get(j));
        arrayList.set(j, tmp);
    }
}

int[] randomArray = arrayList.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
```

Насколько я понял, задача учебная, поэтому выше привел простейший код *перемешивания* элементов. Но на практике лучше использовать что-нибудь готовое, например, `Collections.shuffle(...)`.

Comment: По поводу второго варианта: 1. Зачем вы используете `ArrayList` вместо `int[]`? 2. Почему `K` не зависит от `N`? 3. Почему в обоих `random.nextInt` "магическая константа" `9` вместо `N`? 4. С точки зрения теории вероятностей, ваше перемешивание работает неправильно, ибо не все варианты размещения числа в массиве равновероятны.

Comment: @Regent, 1. Привычка. А так да, тут и массива вполне хватит. 2. Согласен. Вариант `K == N` достаточен. 3. Потому что сначала `N` вообще не было, исправил.

Comment: Первые три пункта - это вопросы по качеству коду, поэтому не критичны. А вот четвёртый пункт, в котором говорится про некорректность представленного алгоритма, по-моему, действительно важен. У вас есть планы его исправить?

Comment: @Regent, Я изменил код. Правда точно не знаю, затрагивает ли данное изменение Ваше замечание, но дальнейшего изменения кода не будет.

Comment: В плане вероятностей стало только хуже. Вы могли бы просто взять код перемешивания из ответов к вопросу, дубликатом которого является этот вопрос, и не мучиться. По-моему, в заплюсованном и принятом ответе должен быть корректный алгоритм.

Comment: @Regent, Ох, ну жаль. Мог бы взять, а мог бы и не взять – сугубо мой выбор. То же самое можно сказать по поводу принятия ответа – выбор автора. А по поводу алгоритма перемешивания – в ответе написано – `простейший`. Перемешивает – перемешивает. На идеальность не претендует.